# How to configure local virtual host in apache2 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I have this in my sites-available/aiki.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aiki
    DocumentRoot /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/aikiframework
</VirtualHost>
```

The apache is running on user kuba and the owner of /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/aikiframework is also kuba.

I've called:

```
sudo a2ensite aiki.conf
```

and I've added this line to /etc/hosts

```
 127.0.1.1       aiki
```

but when I try to access `http://aiki/` I've got 403 forbidden error. I've also tried 111.111.111.111 (as in this article [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)) but got timeout error. I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by adding symlink in `/var/www/html/` to `/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/aikiframework` and use `/var/www/html/aikiframework` path in DocumentRoot directive.